# Reading font names from text file using StreamReader, doubles cpu usage

Tags: c#, performance

I have this code here, and a text file with the name of the font inside. What i try to do is to let users to choose whatever the font family they want, just by writing into that text file.
All works without errors, but the cpu usage, doubles instantly.
What do i do wrong here, ?
I tryied many other formulas but all have the same result, high cpu usage. If i use that comented line with "Calibri", all is fine.
Thank you in advance.

```
private string path = "fontNames.txt";

public Size2 DrawText(string text, int height, Vector2 position, Color.White, FontDrawFlags align = FontDrawFlags.Left)
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(path))
    {
        string name = reader.ReadLine();
        reader.Close();
        return fontRenderer.DrawText(text, name, height, position, color, align);
    }
//return fontRenderer.DrawText(text, "Calibri", height, position, color, align);
}

private Font GetFont(string name, int height)
{
    Tuple<string, int> key = Tuple.Create(name, height);
    if (fonts.TryGetValue(key, out font)) return font;
    font = new Font(device, new FontDescription
    {
        MipLevels = 1,
        Height = height,
        FaceName = name, // "Calibri"
        OutputPrecision = FontPrecision.Default,
        Quality = FontQuality.ClearType
    });
    fonts.Add(key, font);
    return font;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that the `string name = reader.ReadLine();` will be removed/optimized because of it is never used, when using the `Calibri` line? Also, reading the fontname from a file every drawaction, is a bad practice. You should cache it.

Comment: Probably not relevant, but you don't need the `reader.Close` line since the `using` statement will take care of closing and cleaning up the `StreamReader`

Comment: What is GetFont doing in there? Did you forget to use it in DrawText?

Comment: @Matt Yes, i know that, just didn't payed attention to remove it because i have many many versions and i kind of messed them up :)

Comment: @CSharpie  - GetFont is part of fontRenderer, i did put it here for people to see what is responsible for Getting the font to drawText. I can also move the code inside the GetFont, but is the same result.

Comment: @Jeroen van Langen - What do you mean ...can you give an example ?